# Algolia - DateTimePicker - Select Date

Tags: date, select, search, datetimepicker, algolia

I would like to implement a date timepicker with Algolia. If I choose a date, all elements should be displayed from this date.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how I can make this with Agolia.

I hope you can help me.

```js
const datePicker = instantsearch.connectors.connectRange(
    (options, isFirstRendering) => {
    if (!isFirstRendering) return;

new Calendar({
    element: $('.daterange--single'),
    current_date: new Date(),
    format: {input: 'DD.MM.YYYY'},
    required: false,
    callback: function() {
        const start = new Date().getTime();

        refine([start]);
    },
});
}
);

search.addWidget(
    datePicker({
        attributeName: 'date',
    })
);
```

```html
<div class="daterange daterange--single"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

now i have a working code. Now a have the problem.. how i can change in my custom widget the searchParameters?

```js
const search = instantsearch({
    appId: '0000000',
    apiKey: '000000000000',
    indexName: 'Events',
    routing: true,

    searchParameters:{
        filters: 'dateNumeric >= 1531591200'
    }
});

var customWidget = {
    init: function(options) {
        $( "#datetimepickerNotime" ).focusout(function() {
            var date = $('#datefromdatetimepicker').val();
            var date = new Date (date);
           alert("dateNumeric >= 1512752400");
        });
    }
};

search.addWidget(customWidget);
```

```html
<div class='input-group date' id="datetimepickerNotime">
        <input type='text' id="datefromdatetimepicker" name="date" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<f:format.date date='now' format='d.m.Y' />"/>

        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Formik, Field } from 'formik';
import { connectRange } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const RangeFilter = ({ currentRefinement, min, max, refine }) => {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    minValue: Yup.number().min(min, `Minimum value must be at least ${min}`),
    maxValue: Yup.number().max(max, `Maximum value must be at most ${max}`),
  });

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    refine({ min: values.minValue, max: values.maxValue });
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      initialValues={{
        minValue: currentRefinement?.min,
        maxValue: currentRefinement?.max,
      }}>
      {({ handleSubmit }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field name="minValue">
            {({ field, form: { errors, touched } }) => (
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="price-min">To price:</label>
                <input
                  className="input is-shadowless"
                  {...field}
                  id="price-min"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="Min price"
                />

                {errors.minValue && touched.minValue && (
                  <p className="help is-danger">{errors.minValue}</p>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </Field>
          <Field name="maxValue">
            {({ field, form: { errors, touched } }) => (
              <div className="mt-2">
                <label htmlFor="price-max">From price:</label>
                <input
                  {...field}
                  id="price-max"
                  type="number"
                  className="input is-shadowless"
                  placeholder="Max price"
                />
                {errors.maxValue && touched.maxValue && (
                  <p className="help is-danger">{errors.maxValue}</p>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </Field>
          <button type="submit" className="ais-RefinementList-showMore mt-2">
            Get Result
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default connectRange(RangeFilter);
```